# BUILD FAILED , Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleLegacyRelease]

Tags: android, android-studio, software-design

thanks for your time :)
i'm getting this message after building my game on android studio

***Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleLegacyRelease]***

```
  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForLegacyRelease'.
    > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/app/ListFragment$1.class
```

**Information:BUILD FAILED**

i've used a legacy release so i don't know how to solve this problem to get my apk file

this is the gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    dexOptions{
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.companyname.gamename"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        ndk {
            moduleName "player_shared"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        legacy {
            minSdkVersion 9
            versionCode 901  // Min API level 9, v01
        }
        current {
            minSdkVersion 14
            versionCode 1401  // Min API level 14, v01
        }
    }

dependencies {
    legacyCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.0'
    currentCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
        }
    }
}
```

thank you for your help , this is my first game

Comment: What do you have in your libs directory? Can you please tell us?

Comment: I have 4 jar files
dagger 1.2.2.jar
javax.inject -1.jar
nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar
support v4-19.0.1.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you've four jar files in your libs folder already which includes support v4 jar as well. Here are the jar files you have in your libs folder as far as I know from your comment.

- dagger 1.2.2.jar
- javax.inject -1.jar
- nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar
- support v4-19.0.1.jar

The error message clearly shows that there's duplicate entry for a support v4 jar.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/app/ListFragment$1.class

So you need to remove the `support v4-19.0.1.jar` from your libs folder as you already have a support v7 included in your `build.gradle` file which has a different version. So you might consider adding this section in your `build.gradle` file just before your `dependencies` section.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
        force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    }
}
```

You might also consider removing `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'` from your `dependencies` as well.

Comment: thank you sir the problem is solved and the apk as generated successfully , thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to know that helped. Welcome!

Comment: now the problem is when i wanted to install it on phone it says app not installed ! i've tried 2 phones with different requirements

Comment: What does your logcat say?

Comment: please how can i know what does it say ? i'm sorry i'm just a beginner

Comment: When you're installing your application, I think you're doing it by running the application from Android Studio right? So your logcat should print something in that case.

Comment: no i install it directly on phone , and when i that it says app not installed

Comment: Please ask another question in Stackoverflow and give me the link here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46614319/application-not-installed-error-and-not-working-on-phone

Answer (score 0):

You are having `ListFragment` class in your project, that is conflicting with `ListFragment` class provided by Android Fragments pre-defined class. Please refractor your own `ListFragment` class. That should solve the error.

Comment: can you tell me how to that please , i'm sorry i'm just a beginner

Comment: You must be having `ListFragment.java` file under your app/java/<your-package> directory. Right click on that file, go to `Refractor` and click on `Refractor file` and change the name to something else.

Comment: i did but nothing changed , i don't know if i did it right